# Problem when when generating a Tikz code on Geogebra : semi-circle is displaced

Tags: tikz-pgf, geogebra

This is what I plotted in Geogebra :

[image]

That's the code I get when exporting a Tikz file from Geogebra :

```
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-4.370038701302235,
xmax=4.373881990999934,
ymin=-0.5693858009107018,
ymax=5.2038438869554735,
xtick={-4,-3,...,4},
ytick={0,1,...,5},]
\clip(-4.370038701302235,-0.5693858009107018) rectangle (4.373881990999934,5.2038438869554735);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-3,1)-- (3,1);
\draw [shift={(0,1)},line width=2pt]  plot[domain=0:3.141592653589793,variable=\t]({1*3*cos(\t r)+0*3*sin(\t r)},{0*3*cos(\t r)+1*3*sin(\t r)});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=ududff] (-3,1) circle (0.5pt);
\draw [fill=ududff] (3,1) circle (0.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

That's what I get when pasting it into my Latex document :

[image]

Why do I get this ? How to fix it ? I tried several times...

Comment: Do you want to know *why the code is wrong* or do you want to know *how to fix it*?

Comment: @Sigur I want to know how to fix it.

Comment: well maybe report a bug to GeoGebra and tell them to fix the export feature

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is the shift command didn't declare unit `cm`, (e.g. `shift={(0cm,1cm)}`). The following code should work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-4.370038701302235,
xmax=4.373881990999934,
ymin=-0.5693858009107018,
ymax=5.2038438869554735,
xtick={-4,-3,...,4},
ytick={0,1,...,5},]
\clip(-4.370038701302235,-0.5693858009107018) rectangle (4.373881990999934,5.2038438869554735);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-3,1)-- (3,1);
% The shift command has changed
\draw [shift={(0cm,1cm)},line width=2pt]  plot[domain=0:3.141592653589793,variable=\t]({1*3*cos(\t r)+0*3*sin(\t r)},{0*3*cos(\t r)+1*3*sin(\t r)});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=ududff] (-3,1) circle (0.5pt);
\draw [fill=ududff] (3,1) circle (0.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]